# WP8 app crashes and I can't fix this code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've narrowed down the issue as to why my WP8 rss reader app crashes all of a sudden (after installing GDR3 update). The app was working fine prior to the GDR3 update. It all has to do with this piece of code and I cant figure out how to fix it.

```
void get_News()
    {

        news_wc = new WebClient();
        news_wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
            {
                if (ea.Error == null && !ea.Cancelled)
                {

                    StringReader string_reader = new StringReader(ea.Result);
                    XmlReader xml_reader = XmlReader.Create(string_reader);
                    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xml_reader);
                    news_data = (from f in feed.Items
                                 select new News { ID = Convert.ToInt32(f.Id.Substring(0, f.Id.IndexOf(' '))), Title = f.Title.Text, Date = f.PublishDate.Date.ToLongDateString(), Article = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(f.Summary.Text,@"</p>","\n"), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Substring(0,Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(f.Summary.Text,@"</p>","\n"), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).LastIndexOf("Tags")), Thumb = get_Thumb(f.Summary.Text), Uri = f.Links.First().Uri.AbsoluteUri }).ToList();
                    MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = news_data;
                    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                    if (!settings.Contains("LatestID"))
                        settings.Add("LatestID", news_data.First().ID);
                    else
                        settings["LatestID"] = news_data.First().ID;
                    settings.Save();
                    ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update(new FlipTileData {WideBackContent = news_data.First().Title });

                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(ea.Error.Message);
            };
        news_wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.winbeta.org/metrofeed/rss.xml"));


    }
```

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm getting a huge headache attempting to fix this. This is the error I get with VS:

```
$exception  {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean     fAlwaysCopy)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at WinBeta.MainPage.<get_News>b__4(SyndicationItem f)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at WinBeta.MainPage.<get_News>b__3(Object s, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs ea)
at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature     sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()}   System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's in this part:

```
f.Id.Substring(0, f.Id.IndexOf(' '))
```

`f.Id` probably doesn't contain a space, so `IndexOf` is returning -1. You can't pass -1 as the length of a substring operation.

**What to do Instead**

It depends what the problem you're trying to solve is. Are you taking the substring because `f.Id` contains trailing spaces? There should be no need, because `Convert.ToInt32` will handle trailing and leading spaces. If you want to get the number contained in the first part of `f.Id` up to the first space because there are non-numerics after the first space, you could use

```
Convert.ToInt32(f.Id.Split(' ')[0]);
```

This should handle the case where there is no space.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I figured it was this part too. What do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: It's probably in your other `Substring` call then. Check your Regex.

Comment: `Article = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(f.Summary.Text, @"</p>", "\n"), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).Substring(1, Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(f.Summary.Text, @"</p>", "\n"), @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty).LastIndexOf("Tags")),`  You are right! I removed this code and the start page worked, but now I need to figure out how to fix this and make it work.

Comment: It's the same case of `LastIndexOf` returning -1. Perhaps another separate question to help you figure out the regex would be useful if you have any trouble.